# Getting numerical sub-string of fields using awk

Tags: awk, text-processing

I was wondering how I can get the numerical sub-string of fields using awk in a text file like what is shown below. I am already familiar with substr() function. However, since the length of fields are not fixed, I have no idea how to separate text from numerical part.

A.txt

```
"Asd.1"
"bcdujcd.2"
"mshde.3333"
"deuhdue.777"
```

P.S. All the numbers are separated from text part with a single dot (.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
rt$ echo "bcdujcd.2"|awk -F'[^0-9]*' '$0=$2'
```

Comment: Thanks. But I did not get what is the point of "echo" part?!!1

Comment: @user3684042:- It was just to echo the result. You can use it without that!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about any non-digit parts of the line and only want to see the digit parts as output you could use:

```
awk '{gsub(/[^[:digit:]]+/, " ")}7' A.txt
```

which will generate:

```
 1
 2
 3333
 777
```

as output (there's a leading space on each line for the record).

If there can only be one number field per line than the replacement above can be `""` instead of `" "` in the `gsub` and the leading space will do away. The replacement with the space will keep multiple numerical fields separated by a space if they occur on a single line. (i.e. `"foo.88.bar.11"` becomes `88 11` instead of `8811`).

If you just need the second (period delimited) field of each line of that sort then `awk -F. '{print $2}'` will do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[".]' '{print $3}' file
1
2
3333
777
```

Comment: what If I do want to keep space as the separator among fields and just want to split a single column based on dot(.)?

Comment: self-answering question: look for `split` in the gawk manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-split_0028_0029-function

Comment: @user3684042 glenn is correct but update your question with corrected sample input/output to show us what you mean.